# unable to loop through list using jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

pleas check the code below:

```
<%
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add("susheel");
    list.add("singh");
%>

<c:forEach items="${list}"  var="list1">
    <c:out value="${list1}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

This is the code I am trying to execute but unable to get output. Please help me find the problem thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSP EL doesn't use local scriptlet variables. It uses scoped attributes. You code would work if the scriptlet did:

```
request.setAttribute("list", list);
```

But you should never use scriptlets. The Java code should be in a controller written as a Java class. And the Java code should use generic types, not raw types: `List<String>` ad not `List`.

Comment: for some reason in eclipse output is coming as ${list1}

Comment: That's probably because you forgot to declare the taglib at the top of your JSP.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Netbeans and Eclipse are IDEs, not web containers. The web container is what executes your JSP.

Comment: There is some conflict with the taglib jars...can you please tell me which version to use